# Using app.ask more than once function

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Within my function I would like to use `app.ask('blah blah blah');` more than once. However when testing it, only the first `app.ask()` is spoken for which I expected it to also speak out the 2nd response too.

The function looks something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array == ##) {
      app.ask(response 1)
    } else {
      app.ask(response 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(var..` should be `for(var...`

Comment: was sleeping, thanks for the correction, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct - you can only use `app.ask()` once since that will send the response to the user. Once you send the response to the user, you must wait for the user to reply before you can send something else.

You would need to build your response in the loop and then send this to the user. Something like this

```
var response = '';
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array == ##) {
      response += ' Message 1.';
    } else {
      response += ' Message 2.';
    }
}
app.ask( response );
```