# About how to answer twice in response to a single request in Google Assistant (Dialogflow)

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es

I'd like to respond twice to requests from users with Google Assistant (Dialogflow).

### For example:

1. User speaks "Tell us the weather"

2-1. Reply to the user "I will check it, please wait"  [response 1]

2-2. Call WebAPI of weather with Dialogflow (Webhook) (assuming it takes about 5 seconds to process)

~ After 5 seconds ~

3. Respond to the user "Today's weather is sunny" [response 2]

---

So there is a question.

(1) Is it possible to return the response twice in response to one request as described above?

(2) If possible, please let me know how to do it concretely.

(3) If impossible, please tell me the plan for realizing the above.

I am in serious trouble, so please give me an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795674/using-app-ask-more-than-once-function

Answer (score 2):

You can't send multiple responses to the assistant. Even if it were possible to split a message into multiple chat bubbles the entire message would still have to be send in one go to the assistant.

Comment: I think you can achieve something like this with the notifications in beta currently. https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates but I think also preload the data at welcome or some other intent can be an option,  before the actual request make sense if applicable

Comment: I actually tried with multiple text responses, just have to add multiple text response one by one but i never tired text response + webhook